# jquery match element based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, getelementbyid, closest

I'm a noob to jquery. Stuck and would appreciate some help.
Currently building a tool to grab data from a particular page. The page looks like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
 <tbody>  //This is data group 1    
  <tr id="parent0">   //Record 1
    <td align="left"> <---------- text1 here -------> </td>
    <td align="left"> <---------- text2 here -------> </td>
    <td align="left"> <---------- text3 here -------> </td>
  </tr>    
  <tr id="parent0">   //Record 2
    <td align="left"> <---------- text1 here -------> </td>
    <td align="left"> <---------- text2 here -------> </td>
    <td align="left"> <---------- text3 here -------> </td>
  </tr>    
 </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
 <tbody>  //This is data group 2    
  <tr id="child0">   //Record 1
    <td align="left"> <---------- text1 here -------> </td>
    <td align="left"> <---------- text2 here -------> </td>
    <td align="left"> <---------- text3 here -------> </td>
  </tr>    
  <tr id="child0">   //Record 2
    <td align="left"> <---------- text1 here -------> </td>
    <td align="left"> <---------- text2 here -------> </td>
    <td align="left"> <---------- text3 here -------> </td>
  </tr>    
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is a snippet of the jquery:

```
ancestor = $(this).closest("tr[id]");

  matchedElement = $(this).first();
  originalBgColor = $(matchedElement).css('background-color');
  $(matchedElement).css('background-color', 'green');
  $(matchedElement).bind('click.annotator', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    self.port.emit('show',
      [
        document.location.toString(),
        $(ancestor).attr("child0"),
        $(matchedElement).text()
      ]
```

I'm trying to capture all data from just the `<tr>` blocks with id parent0, and child0.

In it's current working state, the tool captures all data within the two tables as text. Ideally I'd like to be able to capture all the `<TR>` blocks separately, put them in an array that I can then iterate over.

Comment: The ID value must be unique, and you're currently assigning the same ID to multiple elements.

Comment: Don't use any id more than once: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('tr[id="child0"]').each(function() {
                         //this will be fired for each matched element
                         $(this).doSomething();
                      }
                     );
```

this way you will get all tr whose id is child0
check this link for more reference http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thanks! That helped figure out my problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using ID elements where you should be using a class.

Instead of

```
<tr id="child0">
<tr id="parent0">
```

Do this

```
<tr class="child0">
<tr class="parent0">
```

Unlike [ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), you can assign the same value to multiple elements with the class attribute.

Then you can select them all like this

```
$("tr.child0,tr.parent0").each(
                          function() {
                             //this will be fired for each matched element
                             $(this).doSomething();
                          }
                         )
```

Answer (score 0):

DO like that...

```
$('cite.fn:contains(blabla)').css('color', 'red');
```

Edit: though that will match "blablablabla" as well.

```
$('cite.fn').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'blabla') {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

That should be more accurate.

Edit: Actually, I think this solution is more elegant:

```
$('cite.fn').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == 'blabla';
}).css('color', 'red');;
```